# mainScreen bounds size differs on iOS 7 vs iOS 8 upon calling willRotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, rotation, ios8

I know iOS 8 now returns the proper screen dimensions for the current interface orientation. To get the device width for an orientation in iOS 7 you had to return the height if the orientation is landscape or width if the orientation is portrait, but you can always return the width in iOS 8. I have already taken that into consideration for an app I'm developing that will support iOS 7 and 8. (See code below)

However, I noticed another difference. If I call this method and pass in the orientation that it will be (obtained from `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`), on iOS 7 it does return the proper width that it will be but on iOS 8 it returns the width for the old (current) orientation.

How can I get the width of the screen when I know the orientation it currently is or will be on iOS 8 and iOS 7?

While I could just swap the width and height for iOS 8, this would return an incorrect value when this function is called while the device isn't transitioning to a new orientation. I could create two different methods but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

```
- (CGFloat)screenWidthForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    NSString *reqSysVer = @"8.0";
    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
        return [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    }

    CGRect screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(screenBounds);
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(screenBounds);

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        return width;
    } else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        return height;
    }
    return width;
}
```

Use cases:

iPad running iOS 7:

- calling `[self screenWidthForOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation]` in `viewDidAppear` returns the correct width
- calling `[self screenWidthForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation]` in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation:duration` returns the correct width

iPad running iOS 8:

- calling `[self screenWidthForOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation]` in `viewDidAppear` returns the correct width
- calling `[self screenWidthForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation]` in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation:duration` returns the incorrect width (what it currently is before the rotation occurs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code to calculate correct width and height for iOS7 / iOS8 before applying constraints.

```
- (void) applyConstraints:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{   
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat heightOfScreen;
    CGFloat widthOfScreen;
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        // iOS 8.0 and later code here
        if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == toInterfaceOrientation) {
            heightOfScreen = screenSize.height;
            widthOfScreen = screenSize.width;
        } else {
            heightOfScreen = screenSize.width;
            widthOfScreen = screenSize.height;
        }
    } else {
        if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
            heightOfScreen = screenSize.width;
            widthOfScreen = screenSize.height;
        } else {
            heightOfScreen = screenSize.height;
            widthOfScreen = screenSize.width;
        }
    }
    //Applying new constraints
    ...
}
```

It is not so beautiful but it works =)

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8, the entire nature of rotation and the coordinate system is totally changed. You should not be using any events like `willRotate`; they are deprecated. The entire app rotates, including the screen. There are no more rotation transforms; the whole app (screen, window, root view) just gets wider and narrower, and that's how you know something has happened (or you can register to hear about the status bar changing its orientation). If you want to know the *device* coordinates, independent of rotation, that is what the new screen coordinate spaces are for (`fixedCoordinateSpace` is the one that doesn't rotate).